# Is there any general way of finding root of a irrational number? (eg, getting $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ from $\sqrt{5+2\sqrt6}$)

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers, nested-radicals

for example:

$(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2 = 5+2\sqrt6$ is straightforward. 
But how can we get $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ from $\sqrt{5+2\sqrt6}$?

Is there any general method to do it?

Comment: Use Approach0 or SearchonMath to find duplicates.